# Can you load a SageMaker trained model into Keras?

Tags: keras, object-detection, amazon-sagemaker

I have followed the AWS tutorial(https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/object_detection_pascalvoc_coco/object_detection_image_json_format.ipynb) and trained my first model using SageMaker.

The end result is an archive containing the following files:
- hyperparams.json
- model_algo_1-0000.params
- model_algo_1-symbol.json

I am not familiar with this format, and was not able to load it into Keras via keras.models.model_from_json()

I am assuming this is a different format or an AWS proprietary one.

Can you please help me identify the format?
Is it possible to load this into a Keras model and do inference without an EC2 instance(locally)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in algorithms are implemented with Apache MXNet, so that's how you'd load the model locally. load_checkpoint() is the appropriate API: https://mxnet.apache.org/api/python/docs/api/mxnet/model/index.html#mxnet.model.load_checkpoint

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I also found the Multi Model Server guide here: https://github.com/awslabs/multi-model-server/blob/master/examples/ssd/README.md that gives some details on how you can actually serve a MXNet model via a webservice endpoint. Still a way to go to make it actually give me the predictions.